# Vue V:model create object dynamically

Tags: object, vue.js, dynamic, v-model

I currently have:

```html
<div id="fields" v-for="(key, field) in ui.account.search_field_url_map" v-bind:key="field.stageName">
   <h2>{{meta.account[field]}}</h2> 
   <input type="text" :v-model="search.field = field" :name="field" placeholder="John">
</div>
```

This div loads data with `v-for` this object has a key that I want to be able to use inside of my `v-model` where data is, inside my data I have:

```
data(){
    search: {}
}
```

I want to create objects inside of `search` based on the data that is being passed through the `v-for`

Right now if I do

`:v-model="search.field = field"` 
I get:

`field: "BillingCity"`

But I want it to be:

`BillingCity: "Whatever input from the form here"`

How can I do this?

Comment: You're using v-model wrong, it is `v-model="search.field"` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html

Comment: That didnt work, it just did `field: ''`

Comment: Doing `v-model="search[field]"` did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing:

`v-model="search[field]"`

did the trick for me